# How I can add "files available for download" to Drupal user profile page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, profile

first time here. I have searched all day for my particular issue with no luck.

I have users that have specific roles auto generated (they purchase a game). I want to display files available to their particular role on their user profile page. I just want to know how I can add a generic view or associate a panel with user profile pages. I want this to display for every user, not on a per user basis. Basically it'll act like, say, direct2drive, you log in and go to your user profile basically and see what games you bought. Seems simple but I am having a heck of a time figuring out how to do this.

I am pretty used to using views but I just don't get how to edit the user profiles like I want to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to install [views_attach](http://drupal.org/project/views_attach), and create a view with a `Profile` display. This displays the View on the user profile pages, rather than on its own page or in a block, and will pass the user's uid to the View as an argument.

Alternatively, if you're already using comfortable using [panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), you can go to `admin/build/panels` and enable the Users panel.  This replaces the user profile page with a panel, which you can add views, nodes and blocks to as normal.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can't believe I missed the panels option. Thanks very much.